# UITextview shows text Arabic but numbers English

Tags: ios, uitextview, uislider

I want to show some Arabic text and the number of `UISlider` Value in a `uitextview` for example:

مقدار= ۴۰

I am using this code:

```
 self.MyTextView.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.mySlider.value];
```

`UITextView` shows the Arabic text correct but the value is adding with English characters. How can I concatenate the slider value so that `uitextview` show them with Arabic characters too.

Comment: Please post code that sets the text of the text view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"]];

textView.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: @(slider.value)];
```

Comment: You should not set the locale unless you want a locale that is different from the user's default locale.